# chartjs add space betwen stacked bar

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Hello I have stuck with add space between stacked bar, I mean I need to add space or margin or padding between bar color

this what I'm done with
[image]

and what I want is like this

[image]

as you can see there's is space between green, red and yellow bar

are possible to add it?

I've trying to add `options.layout.padding` but still not working

```js
const borderRadius = 8;
    const borderRadiusAllCorners = { topLeft: borderRadius, topRight: borderRadius, bottomLeft: borderRadius, bottomRight: borderRadius };
 
    const labels = ['0%', '25%', '50%', '75%', '100%'];
    const data = {
        labels: labels,
        datasets: [
            {
                label: 'LCP',
                data: [
                    90,80,70
                ],
                borderColor: 'green',
                backgroundColor: 'green',
                borderWidth: 0,
                borderRadius: borderRadiusAllCorners,
                borderSkipped: 'false',
            },
            {
                label: 'FID',
                data: [
                    8,15,15
                ],
                borderColor: 'yellow',
                backgroundColor: 'yellow',
                borderWidth: 0,
                borderRadius: borderRadiusAllCorners,
                borderSkipped: 'false',
            },
            {
                label: 'CLS',
                data: [
                    2,5,15
                ],
                borderColor: 'red',
                backgroundColor: 'red',
                borderWidth: 0,
                borderRadius: borderRadiusAllCorners,
                borderSkipped: 'false',
            },
        ]
    };

    const ctx = $('#cwv-chart');
    const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: data,
        options: {
            indexAxis: 'y',
            elements: {
                bar: {
                    borderRadius: 6,
                    borderWidth: 2,
                }
            },
            scales: {
                x: {
                    display: false,
                    stacked: true,
                    offset: true,
                },
                y: {
                    display: false,
                    stacked: true
                }
            },
            responsive: true,
            plugins: {
                legend: {
                    display: false,
                },
                title: {
                    display: false,
                }
            }
        },
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="cwv-chart" height="150"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `options.layout.padding` is just adding space around the chart area and not between data elements.
I'm doing something like that with a simple plugin, changing the `base` of the bar element, at runtime.

EDIT: the plugin has been updated in order to avoid bugs when chart hovering.

See snippet:

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
const plugin = {
  id: 'fillGaps',
  beforeDatasetDraw(chart, args) {
    if (args.index > 0 && chart.isDatasetVisible(args.index)) {
      args.meta.data.forEach(function(item, i) {
         const {width} = item.getProps(['width'], true);
         item.base = item.x - width + 3;
      });
    }
  }
};
const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    plugins: [plugin],
    data: {
        labels: ['January', 'Fabruary', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'user 1 online',
            data: [50, 35, 45, 47, 10, 3, 27],
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(40, 139, 170, 1)',
            borderWidth: 0,
            borderSkipped: false,
        },
        {
            label: 'user 2 online',
            data: [50, 35, 45, 47, 10, 3, 27],
            backgroundColor: 'orange',
            borderWidth: 0,
            borderSkipped: false,
        }]
    },
    options: {
      indexAxis: 'y',
      //animation: false,
      elements: {
        bar: {
          borderRadius: {
            topLeft: 12,
            topRight: 12,
            bottomLeft: 12, 
            bottomRight: 12
          },
        }
      },
      scales: {
        y: {
          stacked: true,
        },
        x: {
          stacked: true,
        }
      }
    }
});
```

```css
.myChartDiv {
  max-width: 600px;
  max-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.9.1/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="myChartDiv">
      <canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="400"/>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: at the first when I run your code, the bar working fine like what I want, but why when I hover , the bar take much space?

Comment: This is happening because hovering the chart it is invoking the drawing. I'm having a look

Comment: I have fixed the plugin and now it seems working well